# Is it possible to save a file in a custom folder inside NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, nsdocumentdirectory

Is it possible to save a file (any type) inside a custom folder in `NSDocumentDirectory`? I mean every time whatever I try to save I use this as resource file path:

```
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject], fileName, nil];
outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
```

or

```
NSString *imageDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

And as a result it always save in the following directory,
`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/......./Documents/file.ext`

But is it possible to save that file inside a custom folder like this:
`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/......./Documents/CustomFolder/file.ext`.

If yes, Could you tell me details about the process?
Thanks in advance.
Have a good day.

**Additional:**

Here, Actually I save an audio voice record file. The name of that file came from current time. I want to save that voice record file in a custom folder.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSString *) dateString
{
    // return a formatted string for a file name
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMMYYY_hh:mm:ssa";
    return [[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] stringByAppendingString:@".m4a"];
}

// Set the audio file
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject], fileName, nil];
outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
```

In `outputFileURL` I save my recorded voice.

I try with this :

```
// Set the audio file
NSString *customDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
customDirectoryPath = [customDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyCustomDirectory"];

NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:customDirectoryPath, fileName, nil];
    NSLog(@"pathComponents %@", pathComponents);
    outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
    NSLog(@"outputFileURL %@", outputFileURL);
```

The folder is created with out any problem but the audio file is not save in that folder.
Thanks.

Comment: what's the outputFileURL when you print it on console? Check that and see if it's a correct file path

Comment: @Puran `NSLog` was showing that there is a newly created folder. But in real it wasn't created. Because `stringByAppendingPathComponent` was missing & `NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];` was the magical line which provided by Mr. Rameswar.
Thanks bro. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You just need to create a folder inside document directory.

```
- (NSURL *)audioRecordingPath:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Recorded"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager  = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:folderPath])
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

    NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
}
```

Then fetch the folder everytime you want to store something and store into it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for commenting & sorry for late reply. It's absolutely working. But the thing which I actually want is added just underneath of my OLD part of post. Can you please take a look on it?
Thanks.

Comment: @Tulon thanks for letting me know. I've seen your question after you edited and here's my code which I am using. I am just passing a string to this method and it creates a file inside my custom folder. Please let me know if you still face any problem or any help required.

Comment: Sharp, quick & fast. It is working. Thanks a loooooot for your effort bro. Take care & stay well. :)

Comment: You are welcome @Tulon. If anyway you know by which developers can stay in touch just like facebook friends inside stack overflow then do share. It will be helpful if we know a few developers so that can help each other. By the way although I've account since long but still new to this place. And I'm glad to help.

Comment: Definitely. But you can't keep in touch with them here. At least not like facebook or others social network. You can knock them by chatting section which is way different. But if you want, you have to personally add them on other plate forms. If you want, you can add me. :)

Comment: in chat room ? I've created a chat room today called "iOS Enthusiasts" but don't know what to do next. Okay no prob. carry on if you are busy. Meanwhile I will check the chat room how it's functioning.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, you can just append the directory name after NSDocumentDirectory and then may be do something like

```
 NSString *customDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
 customDirectoryPath = [customDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyCustomDirectory"]
 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:customDirectoryPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:customDirectoryPath
                                  withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                   attributes:nil
                                                        error:&error];
```

Comment: Looks like Rameswar and I answered at the same time but both are correct answers!

Comment: Oh man I don't know who to vote for! Both are right and were submitted at the same time!!!

Comment: @Puran A big Thanks for the answer. It is 100% correct. If possible can you please take have a look on my "additional" part of the main post. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, at the same time! I would be glad if I can accept both of them for the same time. :( But, If I set the answer basis on "OLD" then Mr. Rameswar's answer comes first. @Acey

Comment: @Puran Yes we both answered at the same time and both are correct answers indeed. Cheers Puran.

Comment: @Acey he he.. Thanks Acey. Glad we both are able to a little. I get more help from this community than I can be able to return.